# creating a subst drive from a selection of folders

Tags: batch-file, subst

I am new to the world of programming and trying to make a small script where I can select a folder with a name that will chance and make this selected folder a subst drive.

The code that I already found on this site is pretty good, but it seems that i am missing a lot of knowledge to make this a working batch file.

The code that I have is:

```
@echo off

echo Select a folder. Terminate folder number with + to open it.
echo/
call :SelectFolder selectedFolder
echo/
echo Selected folder: %selectedFolder%
goto :EOF

:SelectFolder returnVar
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:nextFolder
   echo/
   echo %cd%
   set i=0
   set folder[0]=..
   echo     0- ..
   for /D %%d in (*) do (
      set /A i+=1
      set folder[!i!]=%%d
      echo     !i!- %%d
   )
   :getOption
   set option=0+
   set openFolder=1
   set /P "option=Enter the desired folder: "
   if "%option:~-1%" equ "+" (
      set option=%option:~0,-1%
   ) else (
      set openFolder=
   )
   if %option% gtr %i% goto getOption
   cd "!folder[%option%]!"
if defined openFolder goto nextFolder
endlocal & set %1=%cd%

:SubstK
subst K: %selectedFolder%

pause
```

The folders that I am trying to subst look something like this.

```
C:/system/microcode/brand1
C:/system/microcode/brand2
```

This is the first selection that I want to make. we have to different brands and i would like to choose between the two of these before it continues.

After choosing which brand I have, there is a list of folders which I would like to make a selection from and then subst the folder that I chose. I will be adding more folders to this "type" folders so in the future there will be a "type3" "type4" etc.

example.

```
C:\system\microcode\brand1
 |---  type1
 \---  type2

C:\system\microcode\brand2
 |---  type1
 \---  type2
```

I don't even know if this is possible with a simple batch file but better ask than be sorry.